# ¿Por qué el archivo no se escribe completo?

Tags: c++

Estoy escribiendo un programa usando `c++`, y en una parte de ese programa necesito leer un archivo y escribirlo en otro, el archivo se lee y se escribe, sin embargo el archivo nuevo, no se escribe completo.

Estoy trabajando con el compilador `g++` en `Deepin 15.11`.

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>



int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){


    //Obtenemos el argumento, la ruta del archivo la paso como argumento
    std::string file_name = argv[1];


    //El archivo de entrada que estoy usando es un archivo ".m4a",
    //intento leerlo y escribirlo en otro archivo con la misma extención, sin embargo este se daña debido a que no se escribe completo.
    std::ifstream input_file(file_name, std::ios::binary);
    //Definimos una variable donde guardar los datos leídos
    std::string line;

    //Preparamos el archivo de salida, el cual también es ".m4a"
    std::ofstream output_file("./archivo de salida.m4a", std::ios::binary);



    //Verificamos si el archivo esta abierto
    if(input_file.is_open()){

        while(!input_file.eof()){

            getline(input_file, line);

            //Como prueba guardaremos los datos conforme se lean
            output_file << line;
        }

        //Cerramos el archivo de entrada
        input_file.close();

        //Cerramos el archivo de salida
        output_file.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

El archivo de salida tiene menos lineas que el original.

¿Por que sucede esto?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que, por definición, cuando `getline` lee una línea no agrega el delimitador (en este caso '\n', el caracter de nueva línea) a la cadena de salida. Entonces cuando escribís cada "línea" al archivo de salida, pone todo sin separarlo en lineas.

Para arreglarlo tendrías que agregar manualmente el delimitador que falta. O sea, deberías cambiar

```
output_file << line;
```

por

```
output_file << line << '\n';
```

Tengo que mencionar que esa no es la forma correcta de leer un archivo binario (como una canción), ya que si `getline` no encuentra un carácter de nueva línea en el archivo, va a cargar en memoria todo el contenido y si es un archivo grande es un desperdicio de memoria.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, funcionó, sin embargo, si `getline` puede cargar todo el contenido en memoria ¿Cual es la manera correcta de hacerlo?

Comment: @ftorres [En esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195497) hay un ejemplo.